# Find a $N \in I \ni \left|\frac{2n}{n+3} - 3\right| < \frac{1}{5}\,\forall\,n\geq N$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

I have a question in my book

> Find an $N \in I \ni \left|\dfrac{2n}{n+3} - 3\right| < \dfrac{1}{5}\,\forall\,n\geq N$

(I believe $I$ is the set of integers.)

But I think this finding a value $N \in I$ is not possible, because if I take $s_n = \dfrac{2n}{n+3}$, we know $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{2}{1 + \tfrac{3}{n}} = 2$.

Did I go wrong somewhere, or should I simply write $N \in I$ doesn't exist? Please explain.

Comment: I think you are right

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n = -9$, then
\begin{align}
  \left|\dfrac{2n}{n+3} - 3\right| &= \left|\dfrac{2(-9)}{-9+3} - 3\right|\\
  &= |3 - 3| = 0 < \frac{1}{5}
\end{align}
So $n = -9$ is an integer that works.

Comment: @EddyDXEdilebert I updated my answer.. What I had was incorrect before.